# Cross Referencing Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df=data.frame(1:5, c(2,4,8,16,11), c(4,11,4,11,8))
colnames(df)=c("a","b","c")
df
  a  b  c
1 1  2  4
2 2  4 11
3 3  8  4
4 4 16 11
5 5 11  8
```

I would like to match *every* instance of df$a where the values in df$c are in relation to their match in df$b. My desired output would be some kind of list probably, something like

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 1,3

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] 2,4
```

Any suggestions? I know the match function but that only returns the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be use `%in%` with `which`

```
out <- lapply(df$b, function(x) which(df$c %in% x))
out[lengths(out) == 0] <- NA
```

-output

```
out
#[[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 5

#[[4]]
#[1] NA

#[[5]]
#[1] 2 4
```